# Can i create a type that includes itself recursively?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following data:

```js
const tree = {
    _size: 0,
    a: {
        _size: 0,
        b: {
            _size: 0,
        }
    },
    c: {
        _size: 0
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make it so that TypeScript understands that every key that is **not** `_size` is of type `Dir` ?

I would like to create a type that includes itself recursively. So far, I've got the following:

```js
type Dir = {
    _size: number,
    [key: string]: /* Dir? */
}
```

Where I would like to comment out the "Dir" in order for it to recursively include itself. However, this is giving me the following error:

```
Property '_size' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string'
```

Comment: I would suggest using a structure like `{ _size: number; children: Record<string, Dir> }` instead.

Comment: The problem is not the recursion, but the lack of a good way to say "every key that is not `_size`".  See the answers to the linked question for possible ways to do it and alternatives.  If you can refactor so that the dynamic keys do not coexist with `_size` in the same object, you probably should... your life will be much easier.